# Backreference in Pandas str.replace

Tags: python, pandas

How to do a backreference in Pandas `<columnSeries>.str.replace` ?

I want to access only the pattern in the parenthesis for each of the values in a dataframe column. So I have done this.

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'(<somePattern>)<someOtherPattern>', '\1')
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I have read the documentation of Pandas and `re.sub` is being used under the hood for all the replaces. The Python documentation reads `\1`, `\2` etc. for the backreferences.

What am I doing wrong here !

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example with sample data illustrating the problem?  I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Have you tried using `r'\1'` instead of `'\1'`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `r'\1'` or `'\\1'` instead of `'\1'`, as suggested in the comments.